# C++ events/messages system

Tags: c++, event-handling, messaging

I need to IMPLEMENT(not to use some library/open source) an event/message system.

I have the following restrictions:

- It must be fast. It will be use for games and speed is the main restriction. I think I can't create/delete message/event classes every time a new message/event is sent even if I use custom allocators for that.
- I must be able to predict when a messages/event sent/created will be received.
- It must be easy to use. Doesn't matter how complicated the implementations of the system will be, the programmer that uses it must have an easy to use interface.
- I will prefer to avoid giant switches like on Windows messages, but I also want to avoid overriding a class for only one function - the event handler or something like this. I think something like the MFC style would be nice.
- It must be able to handle lots (maybe 1000/frame at 60 frames/second, don't know exactly this) of messages/events without performance issues.
- It can't use compilers hacks that are not available on other platforms. It must be portable. I will use C++ for implementation.

Any architecture/design/link/book that you think is suitable for/might help this would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah. It'd be nice if you could just have everything, wouldn't it?

Comment: Have you already _looked_ at other libraries, like boost-signals, qt-signals, MPI, others?

Comment: Where are these messages/events going from and to? Are they between parts of the game, or instances of the game across a network, or something else?

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos The best example is from input to UI. But there can be sent from some units to communicate to other units. They can be "logical game events" like a unit is dead and some count must be incremented. To be more clear, can be any type of event that can appear in the game.

Comment: This is a classic example of a "not constructive" question. "This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. "Voting to close, sorry

Comment: @phresnel Yes, I read something about them but neither seems to be "the best" for what I need. I'm sure that are many guys here that already implemented this kind of system that can give me good advices.

Comment: Seriously, I can't even imagine the amount of work that would go into writing AI capable of *predicting* when a sent message will be received. Or perhaps you should focus more on inventing that time machine. Might I suggest that the initial design of your application is wrong? If you're doing something that *really* requires a rate of 1000 frames @ 60 frames/second, you probably don't want to use a messaging system. This all sounds pretty set-in-stone for something that you don't even know how to implement. If the existing libraries don't cut it, I somehow doubt you'll do better on your own.

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan Why do you think that? I think that good ideas can be expressed here and anybody can learn from them.

Comment: @Felics: because, <quote>this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion</quote>

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan I voted to close it and I will try to ask it in other form:)

Comment: @Felics: And, _why_ don't the other frameworks saturate your needs? Maybe you could edit your question to sound like "should be fast as MPI, flexible as qt-signals/slots, and predictable as the tides".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me address your points one by one:

> It must be fast. It will be use for games and speed is the main
>   restriction. I think I can't
>   create/delete message/event classes
>   every time a new message/event is sent
>   even if I use custom allocators for
>   that.

It would suffice and perhaps be even more efficient (it was for me in one project) to reuse and refill existing messages. No need for a custom allocator.

> I must be able to predict when a
>   messages/event sent/created will be
>   received.

You can make predictions but normal networks (you want portability) will make your predictions sometimes a bit off and sometimes way off.

> It must be easy to use. Doesn't matter
>   how complicated will be the
>   implementations of the system, the
>   programmer that uses it must have an
>   easy to use interface.

That should be possible, albeit this could cost you some extra effort. Error handling and special cases (platform, networking) come to mind.

> I will prefer to avoid giant switches
>   like on Windows messages, but I also
>   want to avoid overriding a class for
>   only one function - the event handler
>   or something like this. I think
>   something like the MFC style would be
>   nice.

Avoiding manually written giant switches is a thing I 100% subscribe to.

> It must be able to handle lots (maybe
>   1000/frame at 60 frames/second, don't
>   know exactly this) of messages/events
>   without performance issues.

If you take care during implementation, you should only be bounded by the network.

> It can't use compilers hacks that are
>   not available on other platforms. It
>   must be portable. I will use C++ for
>   implementation.

Not even C++ is available on all platforms. Could you please list the platforms you are addressing?

Comment: Almoust all gaming platforms:)

Comment: +1 I've used C++ on NDS and setup an event system where events were simple objects each contained in the sender object, making no allocation while using them and reusing them. The condition to achieve this is to have no events that can occur twice in the same iteration.

Comment: @Felics, Flash is an important gaming platform IMO.